# Strings in batch

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a string that looks like this:

> str1=start name.txt

How can I save in another string only the word "name" without "start" and ".txt"?
In the end the new string should look like this:

> str2=name

Thank you!

Comment: will it always be 2 part names?

Comment: and is the extension always `.txt` ?

Comment: On the command line `for %A in ("%str1:* =%") do set str2=%~nA` in a batch double the percent signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is unclear because we do not have examples of what your different inputs will look like. In other words, will your string always be 2 characters only? will it always have `.txt` extension? So I am answering based on what I can gather from your question.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "str1=start name.txt"
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("%str1%") do (
  set "str2=%%j"
  set str2=!str2:.txt=!
  echo str2=!str2!
)
```

**RESULT**

> str2=name

Comment: No need to do string manipulation to remove the `.txt`, just use `set "str2=%%~nj"`; this avoids even need of delayed expansion (except for echoing, of course)...